# how to get nth href link in jsp page using javascript

Tags: javascript, href

In my jsp page have nearly 10 href links , but i need to get 6th link using javascript.
can anyone post the code for this?

Answer (score 2):

try something like :

```
var hrefs = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var sixth = hrefs[5];
```

[Docs for `getElementsByTagName()` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 2):

Or simply [`links`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7068919):

```
var sixth = document.links[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var sixth = links[5];
```

More to explore:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

---

Although it would be overkill for this particular use-case, if you're going to be writing a lot of DOM manipulation code, you might look into a good library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They smooth over a lot of browser differences, provide a lot of useful utility functionality, etc.